# How to pass job-specific files to Jenkins as part of job configuration?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job that pulls source code from GitHub public repo. I need to pass some files such as instance-specific configuration files containing secrets to the job and merge with source code prior to running build because these files are obviously inappropriate to be put in public SCM. The Jenkins instance is a multi-tenanted shared service.

The config files don't change often so I don't want to implement using file parameter which forces user manually input the file on every run. Another reason file parameter doesn't work is some builds are triggered automatically by SCM.

I don't want to use [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) either, because the plugin requires jenkins admin access but I want users with job-level privileges manage the files themselves.

Ideally the uploaded files are saved alongside with job config.xml instead of in workspace, because I would like to delete workspace after each build. I can write scripts to copy the files from job config folder to workspace.

Are there any solutions available? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the "special" files are being placed in a folder with say some access privileges to it, couldn't you either run a [Pre-SCM-Buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) to move the files with shell commands, or introduce a regular build step (i.e. after the SCM stuff and before the other build steps) that would also use shell commands to move files?

Comment: Assuming Jenkins is offered as a multi-tenant service, How could the files be uploaded and scoped to a job by non-jenkins-admin user in first place?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the issue here, but I was thinking that you could have some sort of resource, say a mapped network drive, that folks could access/change/whatever these files.  If Jenkins is able to resolve that same resource, it'd be an easy go to do whatever you wanted with those files.

Comment: As the title of the question says, challenge is how to pass files with correct scope. You answer assumes the files are already in-place. Network drive method is a little too backwardish and hard to maintain, especially for dynamically generated jobs.